# How to shutdown application and then read exit code

Tags: c#, wpf, exit-code, application-shutdown

I want my WPF application to shutdown and restart in different ways.
To do this I am using:

> Application.Current.Shutdown(exitCode);

this is easy. But how to read the exit code when restarting?
I have found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa350179(v=vs.100).aspx) solution with

```
int exitCode = e.ApplicationExitCode;
```

but it doesn't exist.

[image]

Thank you in advance for any help

Patrick

Comment: what do u mean it doesn't exist?

Comment: I can't put it in App.xaml.cs. Please see my edit

Comment: `e.ApplicationExitCode` only exists in the `ExitEventArgs`, which makes sense because you only know it _after_ you start closing the application. Afaik there is no out-of-the-box solution to get the ExitCode of the _previous_ application. Perhaps you could supply it in the command line arguments (e.Args)? How are you restarting your application?

Comment: How do you restart the application? That's an important info to give you a solution

Comment: You may restart the application inside the same **AppDomain**, this way you can share data (not just return value) with AppDomain.SetData/GetData (not cleanest solution, I know)

Comment: Save the last exit code in the App Settings...

Comment: That's easy and I think I'll end up with doing it. But that's not what I was looking for.